# My Atomic wallet shows my XMR has a zero balance

Tags: transaction-hash

I have 2.49 XMR that I can not access my Atomic Wallet shows a zero balance and Atomic CS is useless what do I do? Please enlighten me.

Comment: Please try this guide: https://support.atomicwallet.io/article/156-xmr-importing-keys

Answer (score 0):

if you are still stuck you can try to import your private keys into any XMR-supporting wallet.
https://support.atomicwallet.io/article/192-xmr-common-questions

Comment: You should use the comments to include answers like that.